# ng controller having '/' seperator Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angularjs Programming.
Today I reading interview questions on angiular js and I find that ng-controller having some '/' and some names   I am not aware about it  .
What is it mean. PLease help me.

Question 
How to initialize a select box with options on page load in angular js ?

Answer : initialize work with the help of "ng-init"

```
<div ng-controller="myApps/myDashboard/myAccount" ng-switch on="!!myAccounts" ng-       init="loadMyDatayData()">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This use of ngInit is against the [best practises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)...

Comment: No my question is for the ng-contoller. What it mean as it contains '/' in it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it doesn't mean anything special. It's just the name of the controller, which happens to contain slashes:

```
app.controller("the/name/you/want", function($scope) { ...));
```